# OpenSSL Diffie Hellman DER Encoding in C

Tags: objective-c, c, openssl, asn.1, diffie-hellman

I have a problem and spent the last two days searching for an answers.

I generated a DH Object with OpenSSL in C (more specific Objective-C, but I think there isn't something like that) and now can access the p,q and publickey values that are Bignums. I need to send these values as ASN.1 DER Encoding to a server as one base64 string.

On the Android Client the important step is *.getPublic().getEncoded() followed by a base64 Encoding. (* is something with a keyagreement or so)

How can I do that on c or objective-c? Code examples would be very very great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DER encoding, you can i2d_DHParams may solve your purpose.

Suppose you have DH parameters in dh, then you can call

```
  int len;
  len  = i2d_DHParams (dh, &buf);
  //It should write encoded dh to buf and len should be number of bytes written.
```

You can see DH methods [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/dh.html).

Comment: I already tried that but the result is too short. The java docs describe the method a little bit:
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Key.html)
but i don't know how I can do that.

Comment: @Joulez: If the output is in base64 encoding by Java code, then you need to encode this into Base64.

Comment: Yes thats anyway. But the getEncoded() method returns a byte array in java and also gets base64 encoded in a separate step.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to find any solution @doptimusprime ?

Comment: @NikhilJindal: Was not same solution working for you?